# BibTeX language documentation

Tags: bibtex

First of all, since this is my first message here, thank you all for your invaluable answers I have found so far.  I have searched and found many answers here already and usually they were of the highest quality.  Awesome!

Now, my question: I am using `alpha.bst` for the bibliography.  Maybe it's a bad solution, but I'd rather change `alpha.bst` directly than mess around with other BibTeX styles.  It seems all of them have their advantages, but none seems to offer everything I want.

Which brings me to my question: `alpha.bst` is written in BAFLL by Drew McDermott.  Does anyone know if there is a documentation of that language?  I can deduce some workings by reading the source code of `alpha.bst`, but it would be easier to just read a documentation.

Comment: `texdoc tamethebeast`, particularly part 4. You can find it online at http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf

Comment: I've never heard of BAFLL or 'Drew McDermott': link? BibTeX `.bst` files are written in BibTeX's stack language  which doesn't have a name: probably the best guide is [_Tame the BeaST_](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tamethebeast).

Comment: @JosephWright wikipedia's bibtex entry says he called the bibtex language that acronym (it doesn't mention that no one else calls it that:-)

Comment: Note that the bibtex wikipedia entry states that a certain Drew McDermott (I have no idea who this person is) called the language used in bibtex style files "BAFLL". The claim is *not* that Drew McDermott actually invented or created "BAFFL"...

Comment: @egreg: your link seems to do the trick. I would have upvoted this if it would have been an answer.

Comment: @egreg: you may be right. The mentioned article has even more information in it.