# In which programming language are bst (BibTeX style) files written?

Tags: bibtex

I am trying to adjust the bibliography style of `natbib`. There I am facing constructs like these:

```
FUNCTION {emphasize}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\emph{" swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
```

Which language is it? I'd like to read about it to better understand it. Is there a manual? I found some documents, but none of them covered the concept in detail like the TeXbook does for TeX concepts.

Comment: The language has no name and, as far as I know, it's used only for programming bst files.

Comment: Have you seen _e.g._ http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107747/bibtex-language-documentation and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25007/bibtex-defining-own-styles?

Comment: Okay; what would you suggest to better understand it? Is there any chance? I am trying to translate some parts to fit German citation styles (like "und" instead of "and", "Auflage" instead of edition" etc.). Is there an easier way?

Comment: `texdoc tamethebeast` is your friend. [Here](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf) you can find it online.

Comment: @Tobias You do know people have done this sort of thing before? Could you tell us what is the detail of exactly you need to do? People can of course program BibTeX: it's just a bit specialist.

Comment: @JosephWright: That's a place to start. There is a small chapter about those functions.

Comment: @egreg, JosephWright: You are probably right. Thank you for your input. I'll look for or post a separate question with my problem, maybe there already is a solution in combination with `natbib`, although I haven't found it yet.

Comment: It has no name, but it's Reverse Polish Notation, also used for decades with HP's awesome calculators. IIRC PostScript uses the same notation.

Comment: the manual written by the author of bibtex is `btxhak.pdf`.  it's included in tex live.  it's not easy going ...

Answer (score 25):

The BibTeX author [mentions](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/bibtex.web):

> Here's how BibTeX works.  It takes as input
>
> 1. an `.aux` file produced by LaTeX on an earlier run;
> 2. a `.bst` file (the style file), which specifies the general reference-list style and specifies how to format individual entries, and which is written by a style designer (called a wizard throughout this program) in a special-purpose language described in the BibTeX documentation - see the file [`btxdoc.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.tex); and
> 3. `.bib` file(s) constituting a database of all reference-list entries the user might ever hope to use.

A "special-purpose language", as described in [Designing BibTeX Styles](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxhak.pdf), is a form of "postfix stack language":

> Basically the style file is a program, written in an unnamed language, that
>   tells BibTeX how to format the entries that will go in the reference list [..]. 
>   This programming language has ten commands [..]. These commands manipulate the language's objects: *constants*, *variables*, *functions*, the *stack*, and *the entry list*.
>   (Warning: The terminology [..] chosen for ease of explanation, is slightly different from BibTeX's. For example [..] "variables" and "functions" are both "functions" to BibTeX. [..])
>
> There are two types of functions: *built-in* ones that BibTeX provides [..] and ones you define using either the `MACRO` or `FUNCTION` command.
>
> Your most time-consuming task, as a style designer, will be creating or modifying functions using the `FUNCTION` command [..].

Another interesting, related read would be [Taming the BeaST](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf), which attempts to provide the "B to X of BibTeX" - as complete a reference as possible.

[`bibtex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bibtex) itself is written in Web (similar to TeX). While we know it as an executable file, the original [`bibtex.web` source](http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/biblio/bibtex/base/bibtex.web) is [*tangled*](http://literateprogramming.com/knuthweb.pdf) into PASCAL code, and then compiled into a binary executable.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own BibTeX `.bst` files by running

> latex makebst

which uses `merlin.mbs`, [see here](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/merlin.mbs), to generate a `.dbj` ([available here](https://github.com/jaryaman/BibTeX-BSTs)). LaTeX then compiles the `.dbj` file into a `.bst`. With this method, the command prompt will ask you a long list of questions to create the custom `.bst`.

An alternative is to generate `.bst` files by commenting/uncommenting the appropriate lines in a pre-existing `.dbj` file, [e.g. from here](https://github.com/jaryaman/BibTeX-BSTs), and then compile it using e.g.

> latex imsi.dbj

Some example `.bst` files are also available [on this github repo](https://github.com/jaryaman/BibTeX-BSTs).

Answer (score 0):

these cases helped me a lot. It's a simple modification in the .bst file.
I had to change "and" to "&" and also modify the editor function had ", editor" in it and i changed it to "(Hrsg.)". I am using the natbib package with apalike bibliography style. It works fine for me.

[Bibliography: natbib, apa-style and apacite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282237/bibliography-natbib-apa-style-and-apacite)

[BibTeX: Apalike using & instead of and](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164585/bibtex-apalike-using-instead-of-and)

Like they said, its easy to modify with TexShop or any text tool.