# Bibliography: natbib, apa-style and apacite

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, apa-style

At the beginning I used

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apa}
```

and I really like the author-year notation. The result looks fine, but it's English and this time my seminar thesis is written in german. Within the text and the bibliography I need to change the conjunction "and" into "und", and substitute some more vocab like "pages, volume" etc.

[image]

There were some suggestions to this issue and the most promising is:

```
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite} 
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
```

I only need two implementations:

- a cite-version "Smith et al. (2000)" in running text
- and a citep-version "(Smith et al., 2000)" in parathesis

At the moment the apacite-solution alternative citet doesnt work for me, so all my \cite-refs are missing (questions marks within my text).

Another small but important issue are two options for the \citep

- \citep[zitiert nach:][S. 6]{sedlacek2011economics}

Doesn't work anymore. On the other hand a minimal example works very well for me:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,headinclude,bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                         
\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor = black, citecolor = black, filecolor = black, urlcolor = black, pdfborder ={0 0 0}, pdfstartview={FitH}, bookmarksopenlevel=1]{hyperref}  
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black}       

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\begin{document}

I test my syntax with cite like this \cite{beck2014behavioral} and \citet{nudge2008}. And the citep command with \cite[S. 10]{nudge2008}. This also works with double citation \cite[zitiert nach:][S. 10]{nudge2008}

\bibliography{Ref}

\end{document}
```

[image]

My main-file blg. report doesn't list any mistakes. I still try to figure out the MWE/mainfile difference ..

Thank you

Comment: The very actively developed `biblatex` has proper support for language other than English, but it is not compatible with ye olde `.bst` files (and thus also `apa.bst`) it uses a different systems for bibliography styles. If you don't have to use a particular `.bst` file ([and don't submit to a journal that does](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864)), this might be an option for you, the package has author-year styles as well. The `germbib` bundle has `gerapali.bst` a German version of `apalike`.

Comment: You can of course modify a copy of `apa.bst` yourself and change all the English words to their German counterparts. The [`apacite`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/apacite) package seems to speak German as well. See also [Wie formatiere ich ein Bibtex Literaturverzeichnis für eine deutschsprachige Ausgabe nach den Regeln der APA?](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/2686/wie-formatiere-ich-ein-bibtex-literaturverzeichnis-fur-eine-deutschsprachige-ausgabe-nach-den-regeln-der-apa).

Comment: I also found this link, the result looks great, but I cannot implement the solution. There is no error-report; just no result.

Comment: Please read [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) and not that while you are currently using BibTeX you will need to use Biber for `biblatex-apa` on the link. See [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) for that. If it still doesn't work you need to have a look at the `.log` and `.blg` files. (If you don't need to follow real hard-core APA style, you might find that using `biblatex` with just `style=authoryear` - or similar - also suits your needs.)

Comment: Now I am able to use biber.exe and bibtex. And the given MWE. But there seems to be no \citep option instead of \cite. So the underlying syntax seems to be very different. I also cannot use any other reference then the given.

Comment: If you want to stick with BibTeX/natbib, have you tried (a) loading the `apacite` package with the option `natbibapa` and (b) specifying the `apacite` bibliography style? (After making these changes, be sure to delete all aux files and run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.) Assuming you're also loading `babel` with the option `ngerman`, this setup should give you German-based citation callout and bibliography formatting features. Passing the option `natbibapa` to `apacite` ensures that you can continue to use `\citep` and `\citet`.

Comment: Apacite is so extremely different, Im still trying to figure out if there's a a way to reproduce my citation style. citeA,citeauthor,citeyear, etc. are producing horrible results.

Comment: Apacite with natbibapa seems to work! I can't believe it! Still testing all possible situations .... I will repost my final code later.

Comment: Yes `biblatex` uses different commands, but you can enable a `natbib` compatibility mode (so you can use `\citep` instead of `\parencite` and `\citet` instead of `\textcite`). The `filecontents` environment in the MWE was just for illustration purposes you can of course use your own `.bib` file. Please refer to [What to do to switch to biblatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864) for more details on the conversion from `natbib` to `biblatex`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you want to stick with `natbib`-style citation commands and BibTeX and wish to adhere to the current set of formatting guidelines of the APA, you may want to look into (a) loading the `apacite` package with the option `natbibapa` and (b) specifying `apacite` as the bibliography style. Passing the option `natbibapa` to the `apacite` package ensures that you can continue to use `\citet` and `\citep`.

Assuming you're also loading the `babel` package with the option `ngerman`, this setup should give you German-based citation call-outs and bibliography formatting features.

After making these changes, be sure (a) to delete all aux files and (b) rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more so that the changes are propagated fully.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
%% Set up 3 test entries
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{a,
  author  = "Anne Author",
  title   = "Thoughts",
  journal = "Circularity Today",
  year    = 3001,
  volume  = 1,
  number  = 2,
  pages   = "3--4",
}
@article{b,
  author  = "Anne Author and Bert Buthor",
  title   = "Further Thoughts",
  journal = "Circularity Today",
  year    = 3005,
  volume  = 5,
  number  = 6,
  pages   = "7--8",
}
@article{c,
  author  = "Anne Author and Bert Buthor and Carla Cuthor",
  title   = "Final Thoughts",
  journal = "Circularity Today",
  year    = 3009,
  volume  = 9,
  number  = 10,
  pages   = "11--12",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\begin{document}
\citet{a}, \citet{b}, \citet{c}

\citep{a}, \citep{b}, \citep{c}

\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes yes, this is great in principle! Now the german umlaut can be used directly, like ü? But book title for example dont have capital letters. Is there a way that all capital letters in my .bib-file are displayed 1to1?

Comment: So \citep and \citet work, but not the plain \cite command, right? Half of my quotes seems to be missing.

Comment: @Mac - On the topic of how to enter umlaut-characters in a bib file, please see the posting [How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/5001) If `natbib`is loaded (which will be the case if `apacite` is loaded with the option `natbibapa`), `\cite` behaves like `\citet`. Please consider posting a new question on the subject of how to avoid the lowercasing of words in the `title` field for entries of type `@book`. I'm afraid I don't know how to interpret "Half of my quotes seems to be missing."

Comment: \citet seems not to work like \cite is my last big problem. There are only questionmarks for \cite as well as \citet. I'm trying to figure out the reason..

Comment: @Mac - If there are question mark "slugs" for both `\citet` and `\cite`, might that be because `\cite` behaves like `\citet`?

Comment: In the next run I also got question marks for some \citep ... I don't see a pattern in this problem. There are no more mistakes or problems in the .blg file and I also deleted all aux. file around the .tex ... :/ frustrating

Comment: @Mac - Clearly, the document you're trying to execute has features/elements that aren't captured by the example code stated in my answer. Please post a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001)
 that generates the problems you're looking to fix.

Comment: I really cannot do that, in a minimal environment it basically works. But with more references it collapses :/ I'm really desperate.

Comment: I finally got it! Really just one format-mistake in the bib.file because apacite obsivously cannot use url-code with not protected % signs ....

Comment: This works great, thanks. The only problem I get is duplication of `doi` information in the bibliography section, e.g.: `doi: doi: 10.1038/nrn1533`

Comment: @epo3 - Please show the value of the `doi` field.

Comment: @Mico it's `doi = {10.1038/nrn1533},` so no duplicate there. my guess is that there could be some other conflict. Worth opening a new question?

Comment: @epo3 - yes please.